# File lookup() relative to playbook

Tags: ansible

I am currently using `lookup()` function in role tasks.yml to get input from files for shell commands.

Is there a way to make lookups relative to the playbook file (project root folder) instead of role itself? I'd rather store files on playbook level.

Comment: Currently I do a workaround by copying the file to the remote server using `copy` action (which has internal lookup mechanism) and then manipulating the file content on the remote server.

Comment: Could you add a code sample of your intended use of `lookup()`? I'm on 1.7.2 and `lookup` indeed searches at the project (playbook) level.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`lookup()` starts looking up from the playbook directory by default.

If you are using it differently try using `{{ playbook_dir }}\path\to\your\file`.

Its one of the [default ansible variables](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/yrnsx2Mw6rc)

Comment: I am afraid that this is not true. Lookup starts looking from CWD which can be your playbook directory but not necessary.

Comment: Special variables reference can be found here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html